# Modelling technique, how is this workbench created

Tags: modeling, objects, scene, groups, dupli-groups

[In this demo file from the test files from blender.org](https://www.blender.org/download/demo-files/),[(direct download here)](https://download.blender.org/demo/test/classroom.zip) There's a classroom benchmark, If I try to select a desk, automatically the plane gets selected, the desks are not being emmitted as particles, because the modifier stack is empty. The stuff is not parented as I can't select the desk at all. It's not something made selectable because, there no such indication in the outliner. So, I'm confused what is this technique and I'd like to learn about it.

Please spare some moment to download this small file and help me know what is this and how and why is this done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a linked dupligroup.

### Dupligroup

A Dupligroup means that the plane (it could as well be an Empty) generate a group instance at his position. You can verify that in Object/Duplication. It allows to manipulate easily the whole desk, despite it is composed of several different objects ; and it's memory efficient (in Blender's mind, there is only ONE desk).

### Link (linked library)

In the outliner, you can see the list of the different groups available, by selecting "Groups" instead of "All Scenes". As you may notice, the "file with an arrow" next to the name of the group indicate it is a Link : it refers to a group that is in another file (in assets/desks.blend).

You can open desks.blend, and try modifiy something on the desk (ie, change one of the materials). Save desks.blend, then open (or re-open) classroom.blend : all the desks have been modified.

### Why?

There is many advantages in this workflow. It allow easy reuse of assets, it's flexible, it allow one artist to work on the assets and an other on the scene...

It's also efficient because the group is loaded in memory only one time. And the size of each blend file is kept small, this is easier to work with many small files than with a big one.

### How?

In myAsset.blend, create your asset as you would usually, with different objects, modifiers, etc. Once finished, select all your objects and press <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to add them to a new group. Give the group a meaningful name (in the outliner, or in Object/Group). Put your asset at the center of the scene (0,0,0) because that will be his Origin.

In myScene.blend, click File/Link, navigate to myAsset.blend/Groups/myGroup. Now you have an *instance* of the group in your scene, you can manipulate it like any object. To add another instance, just press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> /Group Instance/myGroup.